# Filestream uploading issues

Tags: sql, t-sql, filestream

I am trying to insert a picture into a database using Filestream, I have created the table and columns and have created a Insert statement, but I keep getting the following error message:

Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'id', table 'Racing.dbo.Course_Info'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Column 1 - id - Unique identifier
Column 2 - RacecourseID - this needs to be 11
Column 3 - filestream_data

So can you tell me whats wrong with my insert statement?

```
INSERT INTO Course_Info (RacecourseID, filestream_data)
VALUES ('11', (SELECT * 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pictures for Database\Racecourses\Cheltenham-Racecourse.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as rs))
```

Thanks

Wayne

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you are going to kick yourself here.

```
USE Racing
INSERT INTO Course_Info(RaceCourseID,filestream_data)
SELECT 11, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Pictures for Database\Racecourses\Cheltenham-Racecourse.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) rs
```

would be one way. 
Got to read the error messages RaceCourseID, cannot be null, means you have to put one in.

Comment: Hi Tony, I did notice that and have corrected it (See above) but its the Column 1 - id - Unique identifier that is causing the error.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all: The unique identifier of the row is not nullable, and you are not specifying it in the column list. Another problem is that you are not setting the `RacecourseID`.

To set those two values, modify your query like:

```
INSERT INTO Course_Info (id, RacecourseID, filestream_data)
SELECT newid(), 11, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'filename.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) as rs))
```

The [newid()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) will generate a fresh unique identifier for each inserted row, and the constant 11 will be used for the `RacecourseID` field.